# How to validate the bluetooth MAC address correctly?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have a developer's options pane inside my app, where a developer can input test MAC address of the device. The question is how to validate it correctly? Does Android have some methods out of the box to do this?

Comment: what exactly you mean under `validate`? Do you wna to know if it's format is correct, or if there is such a device with that address?

Comment: if the format is correct. I've already found  interesting solution inside `BluetoothAdapter` check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/58952088/7805359

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank everybody for your help. I found the solution. `BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(String)` validates the MAC address. It checks if MAC matches the pattern given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58951872/7805359), if length equals 17 chars, if all letters are uppercase and whether all chars are **hex** chars.

Answer (score 1):

MAC addresses have this format:

```
String formatMAC = "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X";
```

So you can check that a device's MAC address matches this format using String's `matches()` method:

```
public boolean matches(String regex) {
    return Pattern.matches(regex, this);
}
```